# VBA: Chart.export produces corrupt image - until scrolled over or chart.activate

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have a form that manipulates a chart and then exports it, like so:

```
Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Unprotect sPW
Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export strDocName
```

However, **occasionally** this doesn't work properly anymore and a corrupt image is exported each time. Going to the sheet with the chart and scrolling over it (without clicking) solves the issue for a while. For now I fixed it like this:

```
Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Unprotect sPW
Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").ChartObjects(1).Activate    'chart sometimes falls asleep somehow, maybe this will fix
Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export strDocName
```

This seems to have solved the issue which I dubbed "sleeping charts" for now.

However, I would like to understand how this works, and to fix it without using "Activate" as that can impact the user experience of my users (who use multiple Excel sheets along this VBA-excel form).

Anyone who understands what happens here?

Full function code chain

```
Private Sub C171CmdLe1Dr1Graph_Click()
    Call ShowGraph(1, 1, True)
End Sub

Private Sub ShowGraph(ByVal intLeNr As Integer, ByVal intDrNr As Integer, ByVal Show As Boolean) 'Delete
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim strLeNr As String
    Dim oChart As Frm_DCT_ShowGraph

    Call dle(intLeNr - 1).DrawChart(intLeNr, intDrNr)

    'export the chart
    strDocName = strMyDocsPath & "\DRT_Chart" & Right(strLeNr, 1) & ".gif"
    Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Unprotect sPW
    Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").ChartObjects(1).Activate    'chart sometimes falls asleep somehow, maybe this will fix
    Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export strDocName
    If Show Then
        'create new chart, load it and show it
        Set oChart = New Frm_DCT_ShowGraph
        oChart.DocName = strDocName
        oChart.Show vbModeless
    End If
    Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Protect sPW

    DoEvents
End Sub

Public Sub DrawChart(ByVal intLeNr As Integer, ByVal intDrNr As Integer)
    Dim lngN As Long
    Dim sngPlotArr() As Single
    Dim strIRange As String
    Dim strURange As String

    ...

    'create plot data
    Call cDriver(intDrNr - 1).Plot(sngPlotArr)

    'unlock worksheet
    Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Unprotect sPW

    'clear range first
    Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Range(strIRange).Clear
    Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Range(strURange).Clear
    'fill in data
    For lngN = 0 To UBound(sngPlotArr, 1)
        Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Range(strIRange).Columns(lngN + 1).Value2 = sngPlotArr(lngN, 0)
        Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Range(strURange).Columns(lngN + 1).Value2 = sngPlotArr(lngN, 1)
        'give OS some time
        If lngN Mod 100 = 0 Then
            DoEvents
        End If
    Next

    ...

    'relock
    Workbooks(sWB).Sheets("Output").Protect sPW
End Sub
```

Comment: `Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?  It would help to see the rest of your code since it can come from elsewhere than the lines you're showing.

Comment: which version of excel and OS?
64 bit or 32?

Comment: @simpLEMAn screenupdating is not supposed to be "False" at this point, but I will add "Screenupdating = True" to test this.

Comment: @HarassedDad I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and Excel 2013 32-bit

Comment: I've had similar with Win10 and Office2016, both 64bit so it's not specific to any particular version. You could try scrolling in code rather than activate?